# Get the page URL for button

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm trying to get the full page URl for my button, but i was not able to do that, how should i put the function into onclick?

```
<button onClick='window.location.href'>Button</button>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to get the current location of the browser window? And do what with it?

Comment: @couzzi Just wanted to echo the full page URL (including hash) for my button.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
<button onclick="javascript:alert(window.location.href)">Tell my URL?</button>
```

or this

```
<button onclick="javascript:console.log(window.location.href)">Log my URL?</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.href` is a `string`. setting the `onClick` to a `string` will do nothing, because you haven't **told** it to do anything.

For example, if you want `onClick` to `alert()` a string, this is how you'd do it:

```
<button onClick="alert(window.location.href)">Button</button>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vyyw3ynp/1/

Edit: printing via `document.write()`

```
<button onClick="document.write(window.location.href)">Button</button>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vyyw3ynp/3/

Comment: JsFiddle is broken as you kept the "typeof" in the `alert`

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your answer, the thing is i don't want to get alert or something else, i just wanted to get the page url for my anchor href, this is possible with PHP but the think is i can't get the url hashtags, because browser doesn't send the hashtags to the server, so my only option is using javascript, but i'm not familiar with javascript, is there any way to just show the URL instead of popup alert?

Comment: something like document.write?

Comment: are you looking for `window.location.hash` ?

Comment: Actually, that'd be `window.location.href + window.location.hash` for what you're looking to do.

Comment: I believe that you didn't understand my question, what is the code for echo the URL? i.e onClick="echo(window.location.href)"

Comment: I understand what you're asking, I just don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. See my updated answer.